# CURL PHP handshake failure SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

I have the following code :

```
<?php
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"; // 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'theurl');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'blocPnr_textField_labelNom='.urlencode('www').'&blocPnr_textField_labelPnr='.urlencode('xxx').'&blocPnr_valider=Submit');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "theurl");
$page = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($page);
echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
?>
```

It gives me the following error:

> bool(false) error:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I can't figure out where the pb comes from. I looked for similar error message on Google and S/O but haven't found any solution.

Comment: Are you sure it is a `sslv3 ` ?

Comment: how can I know ? and what are the different version I can try ?  I looked at this (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html) but not sure I understand what to type

Comment: It is a `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1` use this instead.

Comment: It works !! thanks a ton

Comment: The documentation of curl you can find it here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use version 3 of the SSL protocol which is either refused or unsupported by the server. [The POODLE attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) pushed a lot of system administrators to drop support for SSLv3 and its usage is not so widespread anymore (and definitely not recommended).

When you have SSL handshake errors, [try different versions of SSL/TLS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html) until one works (preferably the most secure). If you have a doubt, using `CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT` works in most cases.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT);
```

It seems that **formulaire.sncf.com** supports TLSv1.0. You could also force use that protocol version:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0);
```

Comment: No - start by removing the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION altogether and seeing if the auto-negotiation works (it should). You should only clamp the SSLVERSION if you have a specific need to do so.